# Memory not released when storyboard disappear

Tags: swift, instruments, allocation

In my app there is a `Login.storyboard` and `Dashboard.storyboard`. Once I tap login button I am presenting Dashboard. When I tap logout button, all I do is perform unwind segue to Login. My `DashBoard.storyboard` disappear, but my memory allocations still are the same. When I login again, I allocate a new objects, when I logout, nothing changes. Doing just two things (login (present storyboard), logout (unwind)) I only increase allocations, instead of decreasing it while logging out.

How to fix this? Is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

> In my app there is a *Login.storyboard* and *Dashboard.storyboard*.

If literally true, that's your problem. You don't need two storyboards here - just one storyboard with two view controllers (scenes). If you're going to use two storyboards, then you just have to live with the extra memory usage that this entails.

Comment: No, I very need 2 storyboards... and it is the most interesting... Of course I can unwind to different storyboards:-)

Comment: Why you need two storyboards?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Fine. But if you are going to use 2 storyboards in this situation, then you will have to accept the extra memory usage.

Comment: I know that there is extra memory usage. More storyboards, more memory usage. I know it. But anyway... even I use 100 storyboards, they should be released... but they arent:(

Comment: Storyboards are _never_ "released". That is the point. You have refused to do this with just a single storyboard, which would cause the presented view controller to be released on dismissal, so that's the end of that. Your question is answered.